# How to show a loading image after updating data in MySQL database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

in my index page i used combobox to update the user status to mysql db and then show the value what user selected in combobox. these all worked perfectly (update to mysql, show value what they are selected). i want to use loading(gif) image. for example if user select one option and when they click the update button i need to show loading page symbol (2 to 3 seconds) and then show the value in that place what they selected. how to show the loader image option?

mainpage code:

```
while($a_row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    if ( $a_row['status'] != '' ) {
        if ( $a_row['status'] == 'Confirm' ) {
    echo "\t<td><font color=\"green\"><b>" . $a_row['status'] . "</b></font></td>\n";
        }
        else if ( $a_row['status'] == 'Processing' ) {
            echo "\t<td><font color=\"blue\"><b>" . $a_row['status'] . "</b></font></td>\n";
        }
        else if ( $a_row['status'] == 'Pending' ) {
            echo "\t<td><font color=\"orange\"><b>" . $a_row['status'] . "</b></font></td>\n";
        }
        else if( $a_row['status'] == 'Cancelled' ) {
            echo "\t<td><font color=\"red\"><b>" . $a_row['status'] . "</b></font></td>\n";
        }
}
else {
    echo "\t<td width=166><form method=post>
    <select name=update><option></option><option value=Confirm>Confirm</option><option value=Processing>Processing</option><option value=Pending>Pending</option><option value=Cancelled>Cancelled</option></select>
    <input name=id type=hidden value='".$a_row['slno']."';>
    <input type=submit name=submit value=Update>
    </form>";
```

update status code:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{
if(isset($_POST['id']))
{
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
$update= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['update']);
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE guest_details SET status = '$update' WHERE slno = '$id'");
if(!$sql)
{
    echo ("Could not update to database" .mysql_error());
}
}
}
```

Comment: use javascript setTimeout function with 3000 for 3 seconds. when data send function calls

Comment: if i updated the status once it should show the value what i'm selected (process, pending, confirm, cancel - any one of these).. above i posted the else if statement. look at that coding. that is php. how can able to insert javascript function in php?

Comment: but your question has js and jquery tag. and second thing you can easily attach js you can send data within setTimeout function also..

Comment: Is it AJAX or no...? It's unclear. If it's AJAX, I wouldn't force a 2-3 second fake loading. Instead, in the JS, before the AJAX request, change the spinning loader icon (or add it). When you get the AJAX success, you can then remove that icon.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you would want artificially make process longer, but you could replace this part in your echo statements:

```
" . $a_row['status'] . "
```

with this:

```
<img
  src='loading.gif'
  onload='setTimeout(\"$(this).after(" . $a_row['status'] . "); $(this).remove();\", 2500)'
>
```

Also, all your if-else block could be rewritten like that:

```
switch ($a_row['status']) {
    case '': $color = 1; break;
    case 'Confirm': $color = "orange"; break
    case 'Cancelled': $color = "blue"; break;
    ...
    default: $color = null;
}
if ($color == 1)
    echo //output your form
elseif ($color)
    echo "\t<td><font color='$color'><b><img src='loading.bmp' onload='setTimeout(\"...
```

Answer (score 0):

use ajax for updating the content:
call an ajaxfunction to update contains the loading icon, like the function below:

the ajax function:

```
function ajaxUpdate()
{
    var def = '<img src="./images/loader.gif" />';
    $('#loading').html(def);
    $('#loading').show();
    jQuery.post('update_page.php');?>", {
      id : $('#id').val(),
      update : $('#update').val()
    },
    function(response)
    {
       if(response==1)
       {
          //success area
          $('#loading').hide();
       }
       else
       {
          // failure area
       }
    });
}
```

---

```
<div id="loading"></div>
```

when calling this function the loading image is displayed on the div with id **loading**
and after success of the ajax call it will be hidden.